# How to change opacity of a Xul element at runtime?

Tags: transparency, xul, opacity

I've tried

```
document.getElementById("myId").style = "opacity: 0.5";
```

but it didn't work:

> Error: setting a property that has
>   only a getter

Also looks like there's no "opacity" attribute or parameter (in the `box` or `window` element).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the style as an attribute

```
document.getElementById("myId").setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0.5");
```

Answer (score 1):

The opacity is a property of the style property i.e.

```
document.getElementById("myId").style.opacity = 0.5;
```